# What determines the amount of trophies you win from a battle?

Tags: clash-royale

In Clash of Clans the amount of trophies you got from a win was determined based on the trophy difference and amount of stars you got. Is the same mechanic used in Clash Royale?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The amount of trophies won or lost is based on the difference between
>   you and your enemy's trophies. Generally, if you win against a player
>   who has more trophies than you, you will be rewarded with more
>   trophies. On the contrary, losing against an enemy with fewer trophies
>   makes you lose more.

[Official answer](https://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-royale/?s=battle&f=how-are-trophies-calculated&p=web)

Comment: I am sure this is correct, but not in all cases, right? For example, in very low arenas, like Goblin Stadium and Bone Pit you don't lose almost any trophies to a loss.

Comment: A win generally gives 30 + [your trophies - opponent's trophies] / 20, or around 27-34 trophies, while a loss generally takes away [current trophy count] / 100 + [your trophies - opponent's trophies] / 20