# War star count in Clash of Clans

Tags: clash-of-clans

So say in war a base was already attacked and 1 starred, I attacked and got the 3 stars. However, it only counted 2 stars for me in season info. Which on day 2 was 5 stars and 200% destruction. Why doesn't it count it as 3 stars?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What determines the amount of trophies you win from a battle?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/259257/what-determines-the-amount-of-trophies-you-win-from-a-battle) | Or maybe this? [How is the received number of trophies calculated?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159478/how-is-the-received-number-of-trophies-calculated)

Comment: @Joachim The first question you linked, "What determines the amount of trophies you win from a battle?" is about Clash Royale, a different game from Clash of Clans. The second question "How is the received number of trophies calculated?" seems to be talking about a different issue (trophies ≠ stars). I don't think this question is a duplicate of either of those questions.

Answer (score 2):

Because only the newly added stars are counted as the stars I received.